# How can I have a list of all the file used by a Jinja2 template?

Tags: python, templates, jinja2

I have a jinja2 template that uses other templates with `include` and `extends` statements. I would like to retrieve a list of all the templates that are involved in the construction of the template.

```
import jinja2
environment = jinja2.Environment()
template = environment.get_template("mynestedtemplate.html")
template.render(vartest="Hello")
```

I see only a function for listing the blocks:

```
jinja2Template.blocks
```

Is there a way to list the templates used?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can override the [`Environment.get_template`](https://github.com/pallets/jinja/blob/953acd65b2be5428482dcb60f5b8481b66252ac9/src/jinja2/environment.py#L978) method with a wrapper that stores the given template names into a list:

```
class NameTrackingEnvironment(jinja2.Environment):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        self.names = []

    def get_template(self, name, parent=None, globals=None):
        self.names.append(name)
        return super().get_template(name, parent, globals)
```

so that given the following templates:

**base.html**

```
Greetings:
{% block content %}{{ vartest }}{% endblock %}
```

**child.html**

```
World
```

**mynestedtemplate.html**

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% block content %}{{ super() }}, {% include 'child.html' %}!{% endblock %}
```

the following code:

```
environment = NameTrackingEnvironment(loader=jinja2.FileSystemLoader(''))
template = environment.get_template('mynestedtemplate.html')
print(template.render(vartest="Hello"))
print(environment.names)
```

would then output:

```
Greetings:
Hello, World!
['mynestedtemplate.html', 'base.html', 'child.html']
```

Demo: https://replit.com/@blhsing/NavyAwfulCryptocurrency

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help, I am using ` self.names = defaultdict(list)` and `self.names[parent] = name` in `get_template` to see if a template is a parent.

Comment: It seems that you need to use `template.render` otherwise you will not have any in the list.

Comment: Yes, the template needs to be rendered in order for it be actually read and for any references to dependent templates to be found.